# Python astropy: table and columns objects

Tags: python, list, astropy, fits

I am playing around with Tables object from astropy.table module.

The piece of code below shows the type of data I am dealing with:

```
In [44]: table             
Out[44]: 
<Table length=9>
defocus  source   Chi2  xcentroid ycentroid  FWHMx   FWHMy    Peak 
float32 float32 float32  float32   float32  float32 float32 float32
------- ------- ------- --------- --------- ------- ------- -------
   -0.3     0.0 346.648    2056.5     55.82 11.8635 11.8635 182.277
   -0.3     4.0 148.302   2056.49   1911.02 6.66554 6.66554 299.074
   -0.3     8.0 347.208   2056.51   3922.99 6.83129 6.83129 326.476
  -0.26     0.0 318.489    2056.5   55.8803  10.206  10.206 195.055
  -0.26     4.0 152.501   2056.51   1911.02  6.9012  6.9012 244.817
  -0.26     8.0 285.845   2056.49   3922.99  7.7939  7.7939 236.194
  -0.22     0.0 264.113    2056.5   55.9053 8.79704 8.79704 187.376
  -0.22     4.0 163.228    2056.5   1911.02 2.43716 2.43716 402.182
  -0.22     8.0 230.017    2056.5   3922.99 6.70312 6.70312 235.376

In [45]: type(table)       
Out[45]: astropy.table.table.Table

In [46]: cols=table.columns

In [47]: type(cols)
Out[47]: astropy.table.table.TableColumns

In [48]: type(cols[0])
Out[48]: astropy.table.column.Column 

In [50]: mylist_1 = [x for x in cols]

In [51]: mylist_2 = [cols[k] for k in range(len(cols))]

In [52]: type(mylist_1[0])
Out[52]: str

In [53]: type(mylist_2[0])
Out[53]: astropy.table.column.Column

In [54]: mylist_1[0]
Out[54]: 'defocus'

In [55]: mylist_2[0]
Out[55]: 
<Column name='defocus' dtype='float32' length=9>
 -0.3
 -0.3
 -0.3
-0.26
-0.26
-0.26
-0.22
-0.22
-0.22
```

I was expecting that the two lines:

```
mylist_1 = [x for x in cols]
```

and

```
mylist_2 = [cols[k] for k in range(len(cols))]
```

would de exactly the same thing (the second one being less elegant), but it doesn't, as you can see in the outputs above (mylist_1 contains only the columns names, and not the columns themselves). Why is that so? Is there something I don't really understand about my "cols" object?

Thanks for your insights.

(I ran into this while trying to write my table to a fits file - using astropy.io.fits - which requires building an appropriate columns list, which isn't as obvious as one would expect...)

Comment: There's not a lot about FITS files that's "obvious" (such as my favorite example, being the lack of support for unsigned integers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loops iterate slightly different (but equivalent) over the columns. **But** you append different things in the list comprehension. The columns are `dict`-like so they have an index and an associated element:

Consider a table like this:

```
from astropy.table import Table

data_rows = [(1, 2.0, 'x'),
             (4, 5.0, 'y'),
             (5, 8.2, 'z')]
t = Table(rows=data_rows, names=('a', 'b', 'c'), meta={'name': 'first table'},
          dtype=('i4', 'f8', 'S1'))
cols=t.columns
```

You iterate over the **column indices** by using:

```
[x for x in cols]
# ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

or

```
[k for k in range(len(cols))]
# [0, 1, 2]
```

These seem different but `cols[0] == cols['a']` so these are just two different ways to index your columns.

But if you want to iterate over the **actual columns** not their indices you could do:

```
[cols[x] for x in cols]
# [<Column name='a' dtype='int32' length=3>1   4   5, 
# <Column name='b' dtype='float64' length=3>2.0  5.0   8.2,
# <Column name='c' dtype='bytes1' length=3> x   y    z]
```

or:

```
[cols[k] for k in range(len(cols))]
# [<Column name='a' dtype='int32' length=3>1   4   5, 
# <Column name='b' dtype='float64' length=3>2.0  5.0   8.2,
# <Column name='c' dtype='bytes1' length=3> x   y    z]
```

This time we actually insert the indexed column instead of inserting the index.

This is however no means to your end with the conversion to FITS but you can always save your Table directly into any of their formats see [their supported formats](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/unified.html).

For example writing to a fits is as simple as using:

```
t.write('new_table.fits')
```

or

```
t.write('new_table.fits', format='fits')
```

Comment: it was not obvious at all to me that I iterate over the indices by doing [x of x in cols]. Because with a classical list (say L = [8,12,4,1]) [x for x in L] does iterate over the elements of the list, not the indices. But I understand that my astropy Table is a different object and does not behave like a simple list, thanks to Vince's answer too. Cheers.

Comment: @samR well it's more like iterating over a dictionary than iterating over a list. It's further complicated by the fact that columns allow numerical and string indexing. But I hope I've explained it to your satisfaction. :)

Comment: yes you have. And I can write my fits files easily now! :-)

Comment: Think of the TableColumns as an ordered mapping of columns.

Answer (score 2):

The `astropy.table.table.TableColumns` object (accessed via the `columns` attribute) is an *ordered dict*, not a list.  That is why `[x for x in cols]` gives a list of the column names (same as iterating over a normal dict gives the keys, not the values).

For convenience it also supports indexed access and slicing like `col[0]` or `cols[1:3]`.  But even though it supports list-like access, `TableColumns` is first and foremost a dict.

In [PR #4394](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/pull/4394/files) a new `itercols()` method will be added which will support `cols_list = [x for x in t.itercols()]`.

Answer (score 0):

The astropy.table.table.TableColumns is a defined item of the astropy package. It is an instance of the class TableColumns and basically you should not be able to access to it with iterator "cols[k]" or "in cols".

But in a class you can define the method **contains**() and **getitem**() to describe the behaviour of these two requests. See https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python/web/special-methods.html

Here it seems that the defined behaviours are not similar to a classical list of element. Maybe some doc is available on astropy classes.

Comment: it s __contains__() and __getitem__(), i can t manage to have the underscores.